# YII2 после авторизации отобразить свои ссылки в header

Tags: yii2

Установил расширенный шаблон YII2, сделал БД, произвел миграцию. Настроил подключение к БД, запустил встроенный web server. Теперь у меня есть 2 ссылки на административную и публичную часть приложения. В шапке у меня есть 6 ссылок:
  My Application
  Home
  About
  Contact
  Signup Login

После авторизации:
  My Application
  Home
  About
  Contact 
  Logout(Login)

Вопрос: Как мне после авторизации добавить в шапке ссылку на свою динамическую страницу? Где производятся настроки?

Answer (score 0):

Можете в *layouts/main.php* указать нужную вам ссылку внутри **nav**:

```
<?php if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest): ?>
   <a href="">ваша ссылка</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```